# Python: different byte values for the same character?

Tags: python, text, unicode, ascii, decode

The program I'm writing captures individual keypresses with the function **mscvrt.getch()**, which works very similarly to the C function of the same name, but instead of returning a char variable, it returns a byte, which I have to decode afterwards.

However, it has a problem decoding non-ascii characters, like accented letters (it triggers a UnicodeDecodeError), so I handle this exception with a function that compares the returned byte value with a list of byte values of special characters I want, and if it matches with one of them, the function returns its char equivalent.

The problem is that I noticed that the byte value is different on two machines I use (probably something to do with the system being in different languages, and/or I using keyboards with a different layout).

For example, if I input the character **à**, the byte value returned will be **b'\x85'** in one machine, and **b'\xe0'** in the other.

Why does this happen? How can I make a "universal solution" (elegant, preferably) that can work as I want in any machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`msvcrt.getwch()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getwch).

It will return a `str` (rather than a byte) that contains the character, and works with unicode rather than ascii.

Comment: Thank you! So simple, I wonder how I never saw this function being mentioned on the threads I've looked.